# How to get only text value from the below <li> in dropdown (required XPATH)

Tags: list, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu

Questions:

Currently I am using below xpath to get the text under li ul

```
//*@id=['Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen']/div/ul/li
```

however Output as follows:

> ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (6624880cd868883159df5e5e631e1e4f)]

Expected:

> United States (text mentioned under li)

Please help here to identified the correct XPATH?

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-active" style="width: inherit;" title="" id="Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen">
    <a tabindex="-1" class="chosen-single"><span>Select</span><div><b></b></div></a>
    <div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div>
    <ul class="chosen-results">
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="0">Please select country</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">United States</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Canada</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">United Kingdom</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Ireland</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">South Africa</li>
    </ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath will return a list of li webelements. Iterate the list to get the text with getText method. If you want just USA one append [.='United States'] to your xpath

Comment: As you suggested I used `getText()` to pull the text of the list value...Currenlty that xpath is returning ( ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (6624880cd868883159df5e5e631e1e4f)]) and not returing any of the webelements list. Do you have any alternative idea?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are using Java) You should try using `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.active-result[data-option-array-index='1']")).getText();
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. But no Luck !! Resulting Null... even I tierd with `By.cssSelector()` as follows `#Merchantserviceproviders_country_chosen > div > ul > li` no luck... Any other way?

Comment: Why no luck.is there any exception?? And make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe??

Comment: First make sure provided locator is correct, goto browser console by pressing f12 at that page and execute line of code `document.querySelector("li.active-result[data-option-array-index='1']")` and let me know the result..

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try by adding [2] after 'li' in xpath (/li[2]).